# Deriving properties of the exp function from definition

Tags: exponential-function, definition, axioms

Define exponential function $\exp$ as follows:
$$\exp:\Bbb{R}\rightarrow(0,\infty)$$
$$\begin{align}i) \ \forall x,y\in \Bbb{R}:\exp(x+y)=\exp(x)\cdot\exp(y)\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}ii) \ \forall x\in \Bbb{R}:\exp(x)\ge x+1 \end{align}$$
Book says these 4 properties can be derived using this definition.

$$(1) \ \exp \text{is increasing on } \Bbb{R} $$
$$(2) \ \exp(0)=1$$
$$(3) \ \forall x\in \Bbb{R}: \forall n \in \Bbb{Z}: \exp(nx)=(\exp(x))^n$$
$$(4) \ \forall x\in \Bbb{R},x>0:\exp(x)>1$$
The only thing i managed to do myself was to prove $(3)$ by mathematical induction for $n\in\Bbb{N}$. I also tried to prove the monotonicity directly from definition, but can't seem to find a starting point. Would you please give me hint on where to start with proofs of these? Another thing I am interested in is a proof of uniqueness of this definition. How do i prove, assuming only these two definitions $i),ii)$ that $\exp$ function defined like this is unique?

EDIT:
For the proof of $(2)$ i have following idea:
$$\exp(0)=\exp{(1+(-1))}=\exp(1)\cdot\exp(-1)$$
and by $(3)$ (not proven yet for negative integers) we can continue
$$\exp(1)\cdot\exp(-1)=\frac{\exp(1)}{\exp(1)}=1$$
EDIT 2: What remains is to show that $(3)$ holds for negative values of $n$.

Comment: From (i), (1) and (4) are equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By your condition (ii), $\exp(x) > 1$ for all $x > 0$. Hence if $y > x$, we have

$$\exp(y) = \exp(x + (y - x)) = \exp(x) \cdot \exp(y - x) > \exp(x) \cdot 1$$

giving monotonicity. The fact that $\exp(0) = 1$ follows from setting $x = y = 0$ and knowing that $\exp(0) > 0$.

---

As for uniqueness, the standard technique is to take two candidates and compare them. For example, if $\exp_2$ is another function satisfying the conditions, study $\exp - \exp_2$ and make sure it's the zero function. Or something more natural here is to take $\exp / \exp_2$ and show it's identically one.

Comment: @MichalDvořák I fixed a typo in my answer. It should have been about $x = y = 0$.

Comment: I would be interested in an elementary argument showing that it is indeed fixed by the two conditions above. I really do think you need at least some real analysis here.

Answer (score 1):

I have never come across this definition of the exponential. Where did you find this? Apart from that, let me help you:

Note that we can take $x=y=0$ in i) to find $\mbox{exp}(0)=1$ (it cannot be zero because of ii) as you can see). Also, if we have (4) then we also have (1) by using (i) again. In fact, $\mbox{exp}$ is then *strictly* increasing. So it remains to prove (4).

If there is an $x>0$ such that $\mbox{exp}(x)=1$, then by (3), which we already proved, we obtain a set of arbitrarily large real numbers $nx$ for which $\mbox{exp}(nx)=1$. This must contradict ii).

As for uniqueness, I think you need something a little more sophisticated. Can you prove that $\mbox{exp}$ is differentiable with derivative equal to itself, using the properties you established? If this is the case, you know that its derivative at $0$ must equal one because otherwise property (ii) cannot hold. Observe that this property ii) is actually very restrictive, because for example if we only use (1)-(4) as assumptions, any function of the form $x \mapsto a^x$ would fit the bill for positive $a$.

Edit: as an elaboration, if we know that the function is differentiable with derivative equal to itself, then the *quotient* of any two functions satisfying i) and ii) must have zero derivative by application of the quotient rule, so that it is identically $1$.

Comment: I've found that in scripts from Faculty of Mathematics and Physics from the Charles university of Prague, unfortunately, not available in English version

Comment: I see. If you are unfamiliar with the techniques needed to show uniqueness, I can post a more detailed outline in another comment of course.

Comment: If i can prove that $\exp$ is its own derivative, isn't only thing i could show by the quotient rule that, assuming we have two different $\exp$'s
$$\bigg(\frac{\exp_1(x)}{\exp_2(x)}\bigg)'=0$$ Can i actually assume that $\frac{\exp_1(x)}{\exp_2(x)}=1$? What makes sense to me is to assume that $\frac{\exp_1(x)}{\exp_2(x)}=c$ for some $c\in\Bbb{R}$
Also unfortunately, i can't seem to prove the derivative, i still need to know somehow shot, that $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\exp(h)-1}{h}=1$$, which i have no idea how to show withouht knowing the limit definition for e and logarithms.

Comment: As for the quotient rule: true, but both functions must satisfy i) and ii), so both also satisfy (2). This should tell you what the value of $c$ is. For the derivative, you indeed need to calculate the limit you mentioned. Note that by using ii) twice, you can show that $\mbox{exp}(h) \geq 1+h$ and $\mbox{exp}(-h) \geq 1-h$, or by (3) this is $\mbox{exp}(h) \leq \frac{1}{1-h}$. Now apply the squeeze theorem for limits.

Comment: Can you explain more thoroughly how could I show that $c=1$ must hold?

Comment: Btw. that proof by squeeze theorem is brilliant! But we still didn't show anyhow that $\exp{(-h)}=(\exp{(h)})^{-1}$ as the post says, I managed to prove it only for natural numbers by induction.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. You should apply i) to find $\mbox{exp}(h)\mbox{exp}(-h)=1$, which yields $\mbox{exp}(-h) = \frac{1}{\mbox{exp}(h)}$. Also I should have been a little more careful: the inequality $\mbox{exp}(h) \leq \frac{1}{1-h}$ only holds for $h<1$ of course, but we are only interested in values of $h$ close to zero anyways.

Comment: That seems great, now it remains to show that the mentioned constant $c$ must equal to 1 in any case, how do i approach that?

Comment: This is not so hard to see: we have, in your notation, that $\mbox{exp}_1(0) = \mbox{exp}_2(0) = 1$. We saw that the quotient is constant, so it equals its value at $0$. It follows that $c = \frac{1}{1}=1$.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you very much!